# How to make one word bold in string using strong tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

For my recent project I have been using Typelt jQuery plugin. I used a function called tiType() and inside brackets I've added text. Since I am a jQuery begginer, I would like to ask why tag called strong does not work for me? Maybe there is other way to make word bold?

```
$('#example1').typeIt({
        speed: 60,
        autoStart: false
    })
    .tiPause(1000)
    .tiType('Hello, I want to bold <strong>this</strong> word.')
```

Comment: are you allowed to insert HTML inside tiType method?

Comment: Consider adding a jsfiddle to show an example. Not everyone is familiar with TypeIt, or understands what you're trying to do. Also, please phrase your question to make it clear what you're trying to do, what problems you're having, and what you did to solve it.

Comment: What kind of element is `#example1`? For instance, if it is a `h1` element, then by default it is already bold, so using `strong` inside a `h1` has no effect. Provide the HTML of `#example1` in your question, and if you apply CSS to it, then add that also.

Comment: Would be useful to know the source of the plugin.  There may be other plugins called 'typeIt' - this one looks like a suitable candidate given the method names: https://macarthur.me/typeit/

Comment: I don't know if this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r6oqk6pn/) could help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use  `<b>this</b>` as well

```js
$('#example1').typeIt({
        speed: 60,
        autoStart: false
    })
    .tiPause(1000)
    .tiType('Hello, I want to bold <strong>this</strong> word.')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeit/4.4.0/typeit.min.js"></script>
<div id="example1" class="type-it"></div>
```